# How to preload a website in browser for slow internet?

Tags: browser

I have very slower internet and I want to preload the first 50 pages of reddit. Basically I want to somehow be able to leave it there for a few hours, then when I use it, I can click on anything and it'll instantly show up. At least, just to have me open a page of reddit and have the whole page preload while I do something else then come back to it for instant response.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

**Option 1.** You can easily save local hard drive copies of individual webpages - [see this site for more info...](https://etc.usf.edu/techease/win/internet/how-can-i-save-a-local-copy-of-a-website-to-show-to-my-students-in-a-room-with-no-internet-connection/)

For Chrome, go to the main browser menu (3 dots on upper right), and select More Tools > Save Page As.

**Option 2:**  You can store local hard drive copies of entire or portions of website using applications built for it, [several examples listed in this website.](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-do-i-download-an-entire-website-for-offline-reading/)

**In your case, I would suggest option 1.**
Your internet might be too slow to save entire or portions of websites.  Just save a page or multiple pages, then open them instantly locally.

Good luck,
John